# Spinor bundle of a fibration over a circle

Tags: differential-geometry, spin-geometry

I have a question: I am reading an article and the author is looking at a submersion $Z \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{\pi} S^1$ with $Z$ is of even dimension. We have $TM = TZ \oplus T S^1$. Given Riemannian metrics on $TZ$ and on $S^1$, we can form the metric on $TM$. We assume that $TZ$ is spin, hence we have the spinor bundle $\mathcal S(TZ)$. On $S^1$, there are 2 spin structures, we choose one and form the spinor bundle $\mathcal S(TS^1)$.
It's then not clear to me that $M$ is then spin, and the spinor bundle is isomorphic to $\pi^*\mathcal S(TS^1)\otimes \mathcal S(TZ)$. Could anyone help me with this step please?

Comment: Could you include the name of the article?

Comment: Yes, it's in the end of page 55 here: https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1989-02-01/S0894-0347-1989-0966608-3/

Comment: Since $TM = TZ \oplus TS^{1}$ then it is straightforward to see $M$ is spin. $w_{2}(TM) = w_{2}(TZ) + w_1(TS^{1})w_{1}(TZ) + w_2(TS^{1}) = 0$. Since $TS^{1}$ is a trivial bundle and $Z$ is spin.

Comment: I think because of the direct sum and the submersion metric, I can assume the gluing cocycles $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ take values in $SO(n)\times SO(1)$, where $n$ is the real dimension of $Z$. I can choose the lifts of $g_{\alpha,\beta}$ to be the lifts $(\tilde{g}_{\alpha,\beta,1}, \tilde{g}_{\alpha,\beta,2}) \in Spin(n)\times Spin(1) \subseteq Spin(n+1)$ given by spin structures on $TZ$ and $TS^1$. Therefore it's clear that $TM$ has a spin structure with the induced spinor bundle like the above.